# Websocket in rails not working because of routes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, routes

I create web app in rails using websocket. I create add below in routes.rb

> `get  '/:username'  => 'users#profile', as:"profile"`

after this, i add bellow in Gemfile

> `gem 'websocket-rails'`

and then I add below in application.js

> 

```
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('localhost:3000/websocket');
channel = dispatcher.subscribe('articles');
channel.bind('new', function(article) {
  console.log('a new article about '+article.id+' arrived!');
})
```

The problem is

> localhost:3000/websocket =====> run profile_path (get  '/:username'  => 'users#profile', as:"profile")

how to solve my websocket problem without removing `{ get  '/:username'  => 'users#profile', as:"profile" }`..?

I am new user in developing rails using web socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this using a routing constraint:

`get '/:hash', to: 'conversations#show', constraints: {hash: /((?!websocket).)*/}`

The route will not work unless the `:hash` does not contain the string 'websocket'

I'm sure there's a better regex out there, and if my hash ever randomly contains the string "websocket" it'll fail.

But, this fixes your problem for me in development.